# Hover an image but keep the background one

Tags: css, image, background, hover

When I hover my background image I want another one to be displayed but keep the background one. Basically, I want an arrow to appear over the hovered image, but this is what I get:       (see the bitly link below).
This is what it should look like:   http://i44.tinypic.com/2vnm7au.jpg

```
http://bit.ly/18F2Cqd
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: in css3, you can add multiple bg images.

Comment: Quick solution, make an image twice the size. Top half place the original image, bottom half place the end result.

Make the div equal to half the height of the created image, and change background position hover.

Comment: @RohanSood But I want this hover effect to affect all images that are uploaded to the specific gallery, for example.

Comment: In that case, you would need a lot of effort. You will need to envelop every image with a div which loads a mask (.png format) on hover.

Comment: Why is the jsfiddle link a bitly link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your CSS.
First, the background image is at another url than what you had. And you had `background-image` where you should have written `background`, the shorthand property.

After correcting these errors, I saw the background image was displayed 2 pixels lower than the original one, so I had to change the background position slightly to make the arrow appear in the same place.

```
background: url("http://oi44.tinypic.com/2vnm7au.jpg") 0 -2px no-repeat;
```

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vR7st/3/

Comment: Thank you so much. I've tried so many ways that I've made those mistakes. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to overlay an image over the background one; and that the overlayed image will be always the same.

In this case, the CSS would be:

```
.test {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 20px;
    background: url("base.jpg");
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
}

.test:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: url("overlay.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The overlay file should have some transparent area, so that the base background can be seen.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/nNawD/)